# WebSphere 8.5.5 not recognizing Spring WS @Endpoint annotation

Tags: soap, websphere, spring-ws

I have a requirement to develop and expose SOAP web services in WebSphere 8.5.5. I have developed a Spring WS and deployed on WAS 8.5.5 server [after isolating the conflicting JARs and setting parent-last class loading]. Everything works fine and I am able to deploy/access my WAR file without any trouble. I am using the 4.1.0.RC2 version of Spring and 2.2.1.RELEASE version of Spring WS along with JDK 7.

The problem is, when I login to WAS admin console and click on my application, I am not seeing the section '**Web Services Properties**' being displayed. I don't see my application under **Services -> Service Providers** too. I raised a PMR with IBM and they confirmed their Admin Function will scan and look for **@Webservice** annotation only and not for any other annotation. Once **@Webservice** annotation is found, WAS will flag the application as a service provider. All Spring WS examples that I have seen so far have used **@Endpoint** annotation and I am not sure why WAS is not recognizing this.

We have to configure the login module in WAS [to consume SAML token] and the web admin says it can be done only when the '**Web Services Properties**' section is displayed. The response from IBM made it look like an application problem but I am not sure what else can be done in the application code. I don't want to revamp my code to use JAX-WS annotations. I already tried using '**ibm-web-bnd.xml**' and '**ibm-web-ext.xml**' and the actual WSDL inside my WEB-INF folder but in vain. I also tried packaging my WAR into an EAR but that didn't help. I am using the below line in my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

Has anybody faced this issue? Any wrapper code or configuration to be changed to make my WAR module being recognized as a web service in WAS 8.5.5? Please advise.

Comment: "All Spring WS examples that I have seen so far have used @Endpoint annotation and I am not sure why WAS is not recognizing this."   --  Should not be surprising that WAS looks for annotations from the EE specifications it implements, not annotations from frameworks that do similar things.

Answer (score 1):

Since there has not been any other followup --  if your web module uses a third-party framework that implements non-EE web services, from the application servers perspective it's still just a collection of servlets and filters and not EE webservices the server can manage and provide integration with.

You'll need to solve your SAML problem without attaching it to webservers configuration in the application server.

Comment: Thanks covener!! I was wondering how the SAML consumption is set up in WebSphere for a web module [imagine I have a normal web application and I need to configure WAS]. I also thought of using WSS4J interceptor. Any thoughts?